# Flutter Text overflows parent container with border radius

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a parent container with border radius circular but the text does not follow the same and overflows the container on the bottom left.How to make the text adjust to parent container? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add some padding using the padding parameter in your container and you are good to go!

```
Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),)
```

[You'll find everything about it here.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

use the property clipBehavior and set it to  Clip.antiAlias like the example below

```
Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black26,
            blurRadius: 6,
            offset: const Offset(0, 3),
          ),
        ],
        child: Container(
        colors: Colors.amber,
        child:Text('hello world'),
       ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just your text to new container and give the height and width to it, and do not to forget to change overflow property in Text widget. You can also wrap these widgets in to FittedBox, to size text to the container.